# derive the differential equation when there is an additional time-dependent function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

I have SDE of the form,
$$
da(t)=(y(t)-c(t))dt - \gamma (c(t))dN(t),
$$ where $dN(t)$ is a jump process in Poisson form, $dN(t) \sim \operatorname{Poi}(\lambda)$.
Now, when there is an event, so that $dN(t)=1$, we get $\tilde{a}(t) = a(t)-\gamma (c(t)) $. Here, $\gamma( c(t))$ is differentiable. How would I derive the SDE for $\dot{\tilde{a}}(t)$?

If $c(t)$ is a continuous and differentiable function over time, without any stochastic element, then can I write,
$$
d\tilde{a(t)} = (y(t)-c(t))dt - \gamma(c(t))dN(t) - \gamma '(c(t)) dc(t).$$
Then, if I need to find $df(\tilde{a}(t))$, how would I treat the term, $\gamma '(c(t)) dc(t)$?

Comment: You are using a strange notation. Presumably, your $\dot a(t)$ is $da(t)\,.$ I never heard that $\tilde a(t)=a(t)-\gamma(c(t))$ is called "event" but be it as it may. You have not told us what $c(t)$ is (differentiable perhaps?). Without further knowledge it is not possible to say what $d\tilde a(t)$ is.

Comment: Hi, I tried to edit the question.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. The mother of all SDEs, $dX_t=\alpha(t,X_t)\,dt+\sigma(t,X_t)\,dW_t$ is nothing else than an integral equation: $$X_T=X_0+\int_0^T\alpha(t,X_t)\,dt+\int_0^T\sigma(t,X_t)\,dW_t\,.$$ What is the integral equation in your case? I see too many $dt\,$s.

Comment: Oh, I see the issue, I apologize. The SDE should be $da(t) = (y(t)-c(t))dt + - \gamma(c(t)) dN(t)$. So, I think the integral should be,

$ a(t) = \int_0^t (y(s)-c(s)) ds - \int_0^t \gamma (c(s)) dN(s)$,

since we take given that $a(0)=0$

Comment: Sounds better. Then $d\tilde a(t)=da(t)-d\gamma(c(t))\,.$ To expand the $d\gamma$ term we need to know what $c(t)$ is. If $c(t)$ is a discontinuous semi martingale it can require the [generalized Ito formula](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/01/25/the-generalized-ito-formula/). If $c(t)$ is just a differentiable function the chain rule will suffice.

Comment: Thank you, I was concerned about the chain rule and it got me all messed up. I think the $c(t)$ is just a differentiable function, but I will put in a note. Thank you very much! and I am sorry for the initial confusing notations.

Comment: Hi, @KurtG. I am sorry, but then should the SDE look like, 

$d\tilde{a}(t) = (y(t)-c(t))dt  + \gamma (c(t)) dN(t)  - \gamma'(c(t))dc(t)$.

I ask, because then I have to apply Ito to a function $f(\tilde{a}(t))$, and there I am unsure how to treat the term $ \gamma'(c(t))dc(t)$.

Comment: Q.: "Then, if I need to find $df(\tilde{a}(t))$, how would I treat the term, $\gamma '(c(t)) \,dc(t)$?" A.: Since $c$ is differentiable this term is $\gamma'(c(t)\dot c(t)\,dt$ which is not different from your other $dt$-term $(y(t)-c(t))\,dt\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. thank you for this clarification, I was unsure if keeping the $dt$ was the right expression. Thank you for clearing this up :)! Happy Weekend to you!